# Can not access registry over IIS7.5 on Win2K8 R2 web

Tags: asp.net, registry, iis-7.5, microsoft-sync-framework

I wrote a Web service in ASP.NET using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 and SQL CE 3.5 SP2.
On development system (Win7) everything works fine.

After publishing on a server with Win2k8 R2 Web synchronization throws an error : System.UnauthorizedAccessException because it can't
access :

```
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5"
```

Stacktrace:

```
  Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
  Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, RegistrySecurity registrySecurity) 
  Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeSyncUtil.CreateMachineID() 
  Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeClientSyncProvider.CreateSyncSubscription(Guid serverId) 
  Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeClientSyncProvider.get_ClientId() 
  Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncAgent.GetClientInfo()
  Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncAgent.DataSynchronize()
```

How can I fix that problem without running into security issues?

Thx

Comment: We need to know more about what identity your website is running under.

Comment: It's running with Identity ApplicationPoolIdentity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the ClientId property on the client provider (SqlCeClientSyncProvider) in your client application.